# Applescript: Go To End of File and write Text?

Tags: applescript

Can some kind person tell me how to append text to the end of a file using Applescript? I used the Script Editor recorder to create a macro that helps me clean up some HTML tags. Now I want the macro to go to the end of the file and write a sentence. Is there a 'goto eof' command in Applescript?

Thanks!

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
activate
    open find window
    replace "<b>" using "<strong>" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "</b>" using "</strong>" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "<i>" using "<em>" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "</i>" using "</em>" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "<span>" using "" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "</span>" using "" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    replace "&nbsp;" using "" searching in text 1 of document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
    close find window
    goto eof
    write "hello world!"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this in TextWrangler:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    select insertion point after last character of text window 1
    set selection to "hello world!"
end tell
```

The syntax will be unique to which text app you are using. Plus, you can also append text to a file using just applescript without opening the file in another app. (just search for "applescript append text")